# Nesting async functions using NodeJS and Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, loops, web-scraping, async-await, puppeteer

I am building a small scraper which scrapes a search results page for links and then clicks on each link to scrape the details from the resulting page. So so far I have two scrapers. One scrapes the results page, the other scrapes the a single result's page. This is truncated scraper for the results page:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var URLList = new Array;
let scrapeResults = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('www.******.com/search_result');
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const RESULT_SELECTOR ='#innerLeft ';
    const RESULT_CLASS = 'dspListings2';
    // scrape result page for URLs and put them in global URLList for further processing    
    URLList.push(results);
 browser.close();
};
scrapeResults();
```

and this is the scraper for the individual result page (after link click):

```
var details=''; //to be populated by scrapeListings function
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
URLList = [url1, url2, url3] // URLList is populated by the scrapeResults() function

URLList.forEach(async (url) => {
  const scrapeResultDetails = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const RESULT_DETAILS_SELECTOR = '#details_layout > p';
    // scrape for  result details
    // assign result details to global details variable for further processing
    details = resultDetails;
 browser.close();
};
scrapeResultDetails();
});
```

The results page returns a list of URLs which I then want to pass on to the second scraper so that the `forEach` loop opens each url in the list to scrape for details.

**PROBLEM**
The problem is that I cannot call the second scraper as it is within the first one. Both have `async wait` and this causes errors. For example, this is what i tried and it doesn't work:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var URLList = new Array;
var details=''; //to be populated by scrapeListings function

let scrapeResults = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('www.******.com/search_result');
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const RESULT_SELECTOR ='#innerLeft ';
    const RESULT_CLASS = 'dspListings2';
    // scrape result page for URLs and put them in global URLList for further processing    
    URLList.push(results);

browser.close();

    URLList.forEach(async (url) => {
      const scrapeResultDetails = async () => {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url);
        await page.waitFor(1000);
        const RESULT_DETAILS_SELECTOR = '#details_layout > p';
        // scrape for  result details
        // assign result details to global details variable for further processing
        details = resultDetails;
     browser.close();
    };
    scrapeResultDetails();
    });


};
scrapeResults();
```

Any ideas???
Also, is that where I should be declaring my global variables for the loops?

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch to `[for-of][1]` loop instead of `.forEach` because it works perfectly with async calls.
Also you have missed a couple of `await` statements.

- I would strongly recommend you stop using global variables and just return data from functions.

Please see my comments:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var URLList = [];

var details=''; //to be populated by scrapeListings function

const scrapeResultDetails = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    const RESULT_DETAILS_SELECTOR = '#details_layout > p';

    //TODO: Global variables are bad, consider returning details from a function.
    details = resultDetails;

    //TODO: `await` was missing here
    await browser.close();
};

let scrapeResults = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('www.******.com/search_result');
    await page.waitFor(1000);

    const RESULT_SELECTOR ='#innerLeft ';
    const RESULT_CLASS = 'dspListings2';

    URLList.push(results);

    // TODO: `await` has been missing.
    await browser.close();

    // TODO: Please use for-of loop here, you won't have any async prolems then
    for (let url of URLList) {
        // TODO: `details` is going to be populated after each iterration.
        // TODO: Although consider having `const details = await scrapeResultDetails(); here.
        await scrapeResultDetails();
    }
};
```